# How do I separate strings from uncertain user input in C?

Tags: c, input

I'm trying to take input from the user for a program and the input has the following conditions :

the user will enter a string - either "foo" or "bar" but the strings can have as many spaces before or after.

followed by that the user will enter another string ( that can be anything )- for eg - "Jacob McQueen" or "Random string with 4 words"

So if the user enters - ______foo___Jacob McQueen

('_' signifies a space character)

I need to separate out the strings "foo" and "Jacob McQueen".

How should I do this in C?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use scanf to do the heavy lifting. The '%s' will read the first token (foo/bar), and the '%[^\n]' will read everything else, up to new line, into word2. Length are arbitrary.

```
   char word1[10], word2[100] ;
   if ( scanf("%9s %99[^\n]", word1, word2) == 2 ) {
      // Do something with word1, word2
   } ;
```

If you need unlimited length, consider using 'm' length modifier for malloced strings

Comment: *note:* the `'m'` modifier is non-portable Linux only (and `m` was `a` in earlier versions of glibc)

Comment: @DavidRankin-ReinstateMonica The 'm' modifier was introduced into POSIX as standard. See https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/

Answer (score 0):

```
int extract(const char s, char **key_ptr, char **rest_ptr) {
   *key_ptr  = NULL;
   *rest_ptr = NULL;

   const char *start_key;
   const char *end_key;
   const char *start_rest;

   // Skip leading spaces.
   while (*s == ' ')
      ++s;

   // Incorrect format.
   if (!*s)
      goto ERROR;

   start_key = s;

   // Find end of word.
   while (*s && *s != ' ')
      ++s;

   // Incorrect format.
   if (!*s)
      goto ERROR;

   end_key = s;

   // Skip spaces.
   while (*s == ' ')
      ++s;

   /* Uncomment if you want to disallow zero-length "rest".
   ** // Incorrect format.
   ** if (!*s)
   **    goto ERROR;
   */

   start_rest = s;

   const size_t len_key = end_key-start_key;
   *key_ptr = malloc(len_key+1);
   if (*key_ptr == NULL)
      goto ERROR;

   memcpy(*key_ptr, start_key, len_key);
   (*key_ptr)[len_key] = 0;

   *rest_ptr = strdup(start_rest);
   if (*rest_ptr == NULL)
      goto ERROR;

   return 1;

ERROR:
   free(*key_ptr);  *key_ptr  = NULL;
   free(*rest_ptr); *rest_ptr = NULL;
   return 0;
}
```

Usage:

```
char *key;
char *rest;
if (extract(s, &key, &rest)) {
   printf("Found [%s] [%s]\n", key, rest);
   free(key);
   free(rest);
} else {
   printf("No match.\n");
}
```